# Mechanize and NTLM Authentication

Tags: ruby, mechanize, ntlm

The following code generates a 401 => Net::HTTPUnauthorized error.

From the log:

```
response-header: x-powered-by => ASP.NET
response-header: content-type => text/html  
response-header: www-authenticate => Negotiate, NTLM  
response-header: date => Mon, 02 Aug 2010 19:48:17 GMT  
response-header: server => Microsoft-IIS/6.0  
response-header: content-length => 1539  
status: 401
```

The Script is as follows:

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'mechanize'  
require 'logger'  

agent = WWW::Mechanize.new { |a| a.log = Logger.new("mech.log") }  

agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows IE 7'  

agent.basic_auth("username","password")   

page = agent.get("http://server/loginPage.asp")
```

I believe the reason for the 401 is that I need to be authenticating using NTLM, but I have been unable to find a good example of how to do this.

Comment: This has gotten me closer
http://speakmy.name/2010/01/19/ntlm-authentication-for-ruby-with-typhoeus-and-curl/

I set up the ntlmaps proxy, but can't seen to get that working either

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mechanize 2 supports NTLM auth:

```
m = Mechanize.new
m.agent.username = 'user'
m.agent.password = 'password'
m.agent.domain = 'addomain'
```

Comment: No method username= For Mechanize::Agent

Answer (score 2):

```
agent.add_auth('http://server', 'username', 'password', nil, 'domain.name')
```

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize.html

tested:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 + IIS 8.5
- Ruby 1.9.3