# NTLM Authentication keeps failing using Mechanize (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, mechanize, ntlm

I'm attempting to use the Mechanize gem to login to an intranet website that uses NTLM for domain authentication and fetch some information from it. However, the following code always produces a '401 => Net::HTTPUnauthorized' error:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'logger'

agent = Mechanize.new { |a| a.log = Logger.new("test.log") }
agent.user_agent_alias = "Mac Safari"
agent.add_auth('http://intranet.website.com/', 'Username', 'Password')


result = agent.get('http://intranet.website.com/JobList.aspx')
puts result.body
```

I've tried many variations of add_auth, including specifying the domain using 'DOMAIN\Username' and 'Domain = Domain', but the site normally doesn't prompt for that information on my Mac when I am logging in.

Relevant portions of the log info are reproduced below:

```
I, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.714137 #30914]  INFO -- : Net::HTTP::Get: /JobList.aspx
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.714187 #30914] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-encoding =>      gzip,deflate,identity
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.714222 #30914] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept => */*
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.714256 #30914] DEBUG -- : request-header: user-agent =>  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.22 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Version/5.1.1 Safari/534.51.22
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.714290 #30914] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-charset => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.714322 #30914] DEBUG -- : request-header: accept-language => en-us,en;q=0.5
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.714355 #30914] DEBUG -- : request-header: host => intranet.website.com
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.714388 #30914] DEBUG -- : request-header: authorization => NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIAA==
I, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.965768 #30914]  INFO -- : status: Net::HTTPUnauthorized 1.1 401 Unauthorized
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.965875 #30914] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-length => 1539
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.965926 #30914] DEBUG -- : response-header: content-type => text/html
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.965969 #30914] DEBUG -- : response-header: server => Microsoft-IIS/6.0
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.966011 #30914] DEBUG -- : response-header: www-authenticate => NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAEgASADgAAAAFgokCoX8cqyBcrwAAAAAAAAAAAJYAlgBKAAAABQLODgAAAA9SAEIAQQBNAE8AVQBTAEUAUgACABIAUgBCAEEATQBPAFUAUwBFAFIAAQAQAFIASwBBAE0AUwAyADUAMQAEABwAZQBtAGUAYQAuAHIAbwBjAGgAZQAuAGMAbwBtAAMALgByAGsAYQBtAHMAMgA1ADEALgBlAG0AZQBhAC4AcgBvAGMAaABlAC4AYwBvAG0ABQASAHIAbwBjAGgAZQAuAGMAbwBtAAAAAAA=
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.966054 #30914] DEBUG -- : response-header: x-powered-by => ASP.NET
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.966096 #30914] DEBUG -- : response-header: date => Mon, 11 Aug 2014 08:42:39 GMT
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.966194 #30914] DEBUG -- : Read 860 bytes (860 total)
D, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.967109 #30914] DEBUG -- : Read 679 bytes (1539 total)
I, [2014-08-11T01:42:40.968604 #30914]  INFO -- : Net::HTTP::Get: /JobList.aspx
```

Any suggestions as to why this could be failing? I'm open to try any other ruby-based alternatives out there as well.

Thanks,
D

Edit: I have tried the solution suggested in the following question to no avail: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391345/mechanize-and-ntlm-authentication) I believe this may be because I am using a different version of both Mechanize (2.7.3) & Ruby (2.0.0)